# Como retornar valores en un web service WCF

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webservice, wcf

Estoy realizando este método web, y todo va bien hasta el momento en que va a devolver los datos,"No los muestra" y no se en que me este equivocando.
El controlador funciona, el Repositorio funciona, el SP funciona, el asunto está a la hora de devolver los datos.

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "Get", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
  [OperationBehavior]
    public ResultadoOperacionConValor<TarjetaHabiente> 
  TarjetahabienteCargarPorCedulaNacionalidadyCliente(int cedula, int nacionalidad, int clienteID)
     {
         var resultado = new ResultadoOperacionConValor<TarjetaHabiente> { Estatus = EstatusOperacion.OperacionExitosa };
       try
       {

           resultado.Valor = _controladorTarjetahabiente.TarjetahabientesCargar(cedula, nacionalidad, clienteID);

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Notificador.LogError(ErrorTipo.ErrorMetodoWeb, ex, "");
           return new ResultadoOperacionConValor<TarjetaHabiente>(EstatusOperacion.OperacionNoSoportada, Excepciones.ErrorMetodoAplicacion);
       }

       return resultado;

   }
```

Comment: como estas invocando el servicio ? probaste hacerlo usando postman? quizas estes teniendo un error de http por eso no recibes la respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solución.

En tu clase que realizas para retornar los valores colocale [DataMenber]

y ahora si vuelve a ejecutar.

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "Get", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
  [OperationBehavior]
    public ResultadoOperacionConValor<TarjetaHabiente> 
  TarjetahabienteCargarPorCedulaNacionalidadyCliente(int cedula, int nacionalidad, int clienteID)
     {
         var resultado = new ResultadoOperacionConValor<TarjetaHabiente> { Estatus = EstatusOperacion.OperacionExitosa };
       try
       {

           resultado.Valor = _controladorTarjetahabiente.TarjetahabientesCargar(cedula, nacionalidad, clienteID);

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Notificador.LogError(ErrorTipo.ErrorMetodoWeb, ex, "");
           return new ResultadoOperacionConValor<TarjetaHabiente>(EstatusOperacion.OperacionNoSoportada, Excepciones.ErrorMetodoAplicacion);
       }

       return resultado;

   }
```